# How to find the column position of an element? Or how to find an element by column position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, multiple-columns

In a Web page, I have a list (`ul`) of elements (`li`). 
Thanks to CSS columns, the elements are spread in several columns.

I want to know:

1. In what column is a given element?
2. Is a given element the first one, or the last one, in its column?
3. What is the first element, or the last element, in a given column?

How can I do that? In JavaScript, for example. Maybe in CSS selectors?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have fixed number of items in each column?

Comment: Since the column isn't an element there would be no simple method of acheiving this. You woulnd need to calculate dimensions and work out where each item was.

Comment: What are you planning to do once you know the answers to these questions? In other words, what is your high-level use case? You probably will need to take a different approach, since what you want can be done neither in CSS nor JavaScript (short of replicating the browser's column layout code in your own program).

Comment: @Salman - The number of items in each column can be anything, but we *may* suppose that it is fixed once the page is loaded. But, I prefer if we *do not* suppose that, the result will be more compatible. :-)

Comment: @torazaburo - My high-level goal is to prevent an item from jumping from one column to another when the size of an item dynamically changes (by JavaScript) after loading. Maybe there is another way to achieve that. I did not find any.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco Thanks for the clarification. But I wonder: how can you prevent an item from jumping when it grows so large it no longer fits the original column?

Comment: @torazaburo - "So large" I think you mean "so high". :-) The items don't change width. But, when an item becomes higher, I want him to simply stay in his column, and the column would became higher if need be, there is no limit.

Answer (score 4):

There is no CSS machinery for what you want to do. What is possible is to examine the position of each element, and do some calculations and inferences based on that. Here is some pseudo-code:

1. Get list of all the `li` elements.
2. Retrieve their bounding rects (`getBoundingClientRect`)
3. Elements in the same column should have the same "left" coordinate. So group rects by "left" coordinate, to create groups of each column.
4. Now you can easily find the first and last element of each column group.
5. To see if element `n` is first or last in its column, check if its "top" coordinate is the minimum (or maximum) of all elements in the column it's in.

You say this is too heavy, but let's take a closer look. Here is the code to find the number of elements in each column. This uses Underscore, but it's easy enough to write generically:

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
var rects = _.map(lis, function(li) { return li.getBoundingClientRect(); });
var columns = _.groupby(rects, 'left');
var column_counts = _.map(columns, function(c) { return c.length; });
```

Comment: Thank you. This is clever. But this approach is too heavy.

Comment: And do you have an idea for preventing the jumps then? :-)